# member of audio group cant access /dev/dsp to play sound

Tags: python, linux, audio, permissions

I'm trying to play a tone with python using the following script referenced here:
http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=49360

```
python -c "freq=220;sec=2;from math import sin,pi;rate=8000;w=                 
[chr(127+int(127*sin(i*2*pi*freq/rate))) for i in     xrange(rate)]*sec;s=''.join(w);print s" >/dev/dspi in      
xrange(rate)]*sec
```

I get a permission denied error 
/dev/dsp: Permission denied

I am root and my user is a member of the audio group.
Is there something I am missing? I am using ubuntu 11.04

Comment: It's because /dev/dsp was removed in ubuntu
[Missing /dev/dsp under Ubuntu][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/244173/missing-dev-dsp-under-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because /dev/dsp was removed in ubuntu
[Missing /dev/dsp under Ubuntu](https://superuser.com/questions/244173/missing-dev-dsp-under-ubuntu)

Running these commands instead will work:

```
 python -c "freq=220;sec=2;from math import sin,pi;rate=8000;w=[chr(127+int(127*sin(i*2*pi*freq/rate))) for i in xrange(rate)]*sec;s=''.join(w);print s"  > tmp_sound
 pacat tmp_sound    >padsp
```

Comment: Must've had a mixup. The command you sent works. Thanks a million!